# Array filter work on older version of mongoose and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, node-mongodb-native

This error gives when you have mongoose and mongo db version is out of updated

```
{
message: No array filter found for identifier ele in path 
membersArray.$[].challenge_video.$[ele].status,
driver: true, index: 0, code: 2, 
errmsg: No array filter found for identifier ele in path membersArray.$[].challenge_video.$[ele].status
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after two days of finding solution i got it simply uninstall older version of mongo
and install mongodb LTS then update mongoose also
In my package.json it written "mongoose": "*",

after install mongoose update version it change's to "mongoose": "^5.10.9"

Now working awesome! Yes got the solution.